# Bash gunzip error

Tags: bash, gunzip

While trying to restore the file "derp" the terminal prints 
derp0000644000175000017500000000000512343302711011660 0ustar  UserUserDerp
and does not unpack the files , i am confused can someone help me ?

```
# let the user choose what they want to Restore
echo -n "Select the file or directory you want to Restore" 
read chosendata 

echo -e "Starting Restore"

# unziping files
gunzip -c ${chosendata}
 # end the backup.
echo -e "Restore complete"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"gunzip -c" unzips to stdout rather than to a file. Use "man gunzip" to review options for gunzip.

Comment: ok i removed the -c and now i just have a . tar file not a .tar.gz

how do i redirect the file that i get from the new code to 
tar xvf filename.tar

Comment: If the original file is tarred and then gzipped, normally you'd do tar xzvf to unzip and untar it in one step. Alternatively you can use "gunzip -c" to unzip to stdout, then pipe that to tar to untar, then do whatever you want with the resulting output.